# AutoSize feature in a label in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-interface, resize, silverlight-5.0

I have a Label object in my Silverlight 5.0 application, and I will need the label to autosize at runtime, either by getting larger or smaller.

My application presents a new number to a user with a set number of digits every few seconds, and at a certain interval, based on multiple factors as the application runs, I either add a digit or subtract a digit from the number length.  I have done this easily in Windows forms, but I need to convert it to Silverlight, and the label control does not have an autosize property.

I have seen the number get as small as 3 digits, and as long as 10 digits.

What would be the best way to go about adding an autosize feature to the label in silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an embedded TextBlock instead of a label.

Comment: Thank You.  I'm still new to Silverlight, and was equating a Label as being similar to a Label in Windows forms.  TextBlock is working great

Comment: The TextBlock works better than the label, but still no autosize functionality.  As of right now, I've got the textblock spanning the entire width of the application control so that the text doesn't get cutoff.

Comment: @DanielShaw Try looking at this link - This is where I got the idea. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightarchieve/thread/60f9140d-5394-4fae-8e6c-33e9f2726020/